# How to create filters for Jinput?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jinput

I have gone through with the [JInput Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput).

We can access the JInput object like this:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

If we are retrieving more values, it would be useful to store the JInput object in a variable so we don’t need to call `JFactory::getApplication()` every time we are doing that:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

To retrieve a value from JInput we need to use its get method:

```
$data = $jinput->get('varname', 'default_value', 'filter');
```

As you can see, it has 3 parameters:

1. the variable name
2. the default value (defaults to null)
3. the filter name (defaults to cmd)

And here comes my question regarding the 3rd parameter.

How can I make my own filter for `Jinput`?
For example if I have to validate phone numbers or IP address then how can I make my own filter for that?

Comment: This for me is 'question of the year' so far...+1

Comment: me too, +1 - already asked about that customizable filter

Answer (score 2):

this is quite simple

In first of it create an custom Jinput class such as `class JinputTelephone` // what ever you want.

perhaps, have a look in existing inputfilter classes under /libraries/joomla/input

// Modify the getter and filterMethod as you want

```
/**
 * Gets a value from the input data.
 *
 * @param   string  $name     Name of the value to get.
 * @param   mixed   $default  Default value to return if variable does not exist.
 * @param   string  $filter   Filter to apply to the value.
 *
 * @return  mixed  The filtered input value.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public function get($name, $default = null, $filter = 'cmd')
{
    if('phonyfilter'=== $filter){ 
    // here we ca got with static filter classes like for formvalidation  or 
    }        
    elseif (isset($this->data[$name]))
    {
        return $this->filter->clean($this->data[$name], $filter);
    }

    return $default;
}
```

// usage

```
$phoneInput = new JinputTelephone();
$phoneInput->get('anPhoneNumber','0040','phonyfilter');
```

// with this method you can also use the regular input handling
   // But you can't use it with JApplication an input

There are many other ways to do that
Another solution
$data = MyFilter::SanitizeNumber($jinput->get('varname', 'default_value', 'raw'));

does it helps you?

Answer (score 1):

My try,

i see that you have some experience with joomla so i will just put my few cents into it.

1. you need to create system plugin
2. you need to create a method after init or similar.
3. now you need to initiate `JLoader` if i'm not wrong and add path to libraries a.k.a. `/plugins/system/myplugin/libraries/newfilter.php`
4. enable plugin and profit ; )

PS. you can create by this way an overrides too joomla core libraries and platform. Such a Curl SSL problem with certs ; )

regards